# Accessing pointers in a pointer to a union

Tags: c, pointers, struct, unions

So I have structure containing a union as follows:

```
struct FILL{
  char *name;
  int id;
};

struct TEST{
  union{
    struct FILL *fill;
    int type;
  } *uni;
};
```

I don't understand how to access the union members within the structure. I've been trying to do it as follows:

```
struct TEST *test_struct, *test_int;

test_struct = malloc(sizeof(struct TEST));
test_struct->uni = malloc(sizeof(struct TEST));
test_struct->uni->fill->name = NULL;
test->struct->uni->fill->id = 5;

test_int = malloc(sizeof(int));
test_int->uni->type = 10;
```

But I get segfaults when I try this. Am I accessing these wrong? How should I do it otherwise?

Edit: Sorry I was focusing on the formatting and I screwed up the declaration for TEST. Its been fixed.

Comment: How about providing a complete and correct declaration of `struct TEST`?  The one you presented seems to be truncated.

Comment: No sorry that was a mistake on my part, I've corrected it but that was the complete declaration.

Comment: What is the purpose of `type` inside the union, if you're never going to be able to use it? You should put `type` in the struct and the rest in the union.

Comment: Why would I never be able to use it? The idea was that I either want type or fill in the TEST structure.

Comment: I would suggest that you try to write a version that *doesn't* dynamically allocate everything.  Right now you're trying to understand unions while also having trouble with dynamic allocation.  Figure those two things out separately, then worry about combining them.  As fluter's answer points out, your current issues are actually more on the allocation side of things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each of the pointer members of the struct must be initialized, either by allocate dynamic storage by `malloc`, or assign to other variables. Here are the problems of your code:

```
struct TEST *test_struct, *test_int;

test_struct = malloc(sizeof(struct TEST));
test_struct->uni = malloc(sizeof(struct TEST)); // uni should be allocated with size of the union, not the struct
test_struct->uni->fill->name = NULL; // uni->fill is a pointer to struct FILL, it should be allocated too before accessing its members
test->struct->uni->fill->id = 5;

test_int = malloc(sizeof(int)); // test_int is of type struct TEST, you are allocating a integer here
test_int->uni->type = 10; // same, uni not allocated
```

So try the following fix:

```
struct TEST *test_struct, *test_int;

test_struct = malloc(sizeof(struct TEST));
test_struct->uni = malloc(sizeof(*test_struct->uni));        
test_struct->uni->fill = malloc(sizeof(struct FILL));
test_struct->uni->fill->name = NULL;
test_struct->uni->fill->id = 5;

test_int = malloc(sizeof(struct TEST));
test_int->uni = malloc(sizeof(*test_struct->uni));
```

Comment: what's the problem? why the down?

Comment: I'm not sure who did? But that was exactly what I needed thank you very much! It seems like I had a fundemental misunderstanding on unions, I thought that when I was allocating memory that I would be allocating for whatever member of the union I was using and the union would be the size of that member.